# Does RethinkDB have a command line client (a prompt)?

Tags: rethinkdb

Does RethinkDB have an integrated command line client like psql?

I have seen the web admin console, but it's very easy to interact with bash script or manually from a ssh on trouble...

I have seen:

https://github.com/stiang/recli

And also an issue is related to this question:

https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/189

but the solution is unclear, rethinkdb repl doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, RethinkDB does not have an official "shell" or "query CLI". As you've found, we do have the Data Explorer in the WebUI which will allow you to do anything you can do with a driver.

What I usually do, since I have RethinkDB running on most of my machines, I just added two lines to my `ipython` configuration to load the `rethinkdb` driver on startup and make a connection to my local database.

This is just a couple steps:

1. `ipython profile create` creates `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`
2. In this config file edit `c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines` (line 35) like so:

   ```
   c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = [
     "import rethinkdb as r",
     "conn = r.connect()"
   ]
   ```
3. Now when you begin `ipython` you'll see that `conn is already an established connection to RethinkDB.

   ```
   $ ipython3
   Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul 28 2016, 21:28:00)
   Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

   IPython 5.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
   ?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
   %quickref -> Quick reference.
   help      -> Python's own help system.
   object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

   In [1]: conn
   Out[1]: <rethinkdb.net.DefaultConnection at 0x109d8c4e0>

   In [2]: r.db_list().run(conn)
   Out[2]:
   ['asyncio',
    'example',
    ...]
   ```

This makes turning `ipython` into your "ReQL-cli" a bit more convenient.

Comment: Thank you ! I will make a combination with recli! perhaps do you know howto stop a running rethinkdb daemon ? (without killing it with pid or killall...)

Comment: Depends on how you installed it! If you're on Mac and installed with `brew` check out `brew info rethinkdb`, if you're on Ubuntu `sudo service stop rethinkdb` should work.